# I want to print the number with the highest frequency

Tags: c#, frequency

I want to print the number with the highest frequency.

for example

if the array = {1,2,2,3,4}

the result = 2

like this... how could I solve it?!

Comment: Let's think this through.  Each element needs to track it's own number of occurrences.  Sounds like a job for a Dictionary.

Comment: int[] array = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 4 };
            var frequecy = array.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).First().Key;

Comment: @MongZhu `is this homework?`  That isn't relevant.

Comment: with linq: group by, order desc by count, take first

Comment: @MongZhu See [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

you can define a counter and You must use nested loop
I am soo sorry I don' t know C # syntax
**in cause I have written it in Java**

```
 public static double frequency(double[] arr)
    {
        int c = 0;
        int max = 1 ;
        double frequency = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0 ; i<arr.length ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0 ;j<arr.length ; j++)
            {
                if(arr[i] == arr[j])
                {
                    c++;
                }
            }
            if(c> max)
            {
                frequency = arr[i];
            }
            c=0;

        }
        return frequency;
    }
```

Comment: Actually I agree with you , but I don't know  how to improve myself using StackOverflow then I have learned it I hope he will learn how to use Stack to improve yourself code skills